# Can't expand php snippet inside html attribute?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I have a snippet to expand php with echo.

```
    "php variable": {
        "scope": "html",
        "prefix": "pv",
        "body": [
            "<?php echo $1 ?>"
        ],
        "description": "PHP expand"
    },
```

and image html tag

```
<img src="pv" alt="">
```

And `pv` don't work.
Now to use this snippet, i need to type pv outside image tag and move inside.
How to fix that?

I tried to use snippet for js